# mounted network disk with cifs doesn't allow to move created folders

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions, directory, cifs

I can create, delete and rename folder (as long, as it is stays on the same level) on an cifs connected network disk, but I cannot move them.
When I try to move one dir inside of another dir, it gives me access denied.
When I login to the ssh and move the folder from the remote shell, it works.
Maybe, I need to use some parameter, that I am missing with cifs connection string?

Here is my string:

```
mount -t cifs //ip.addr/share_name /tmp/mount_dir/ -o user=user-with-root-rights,domain=domain-or-workgroup-name,uid=local-user-mapped2mount,gid=local-group-mapped2mount
```

Comment: What is the platform the network disk is using? If it is Linux, most likely the reason is that the daemon is running as a user that has does not have permissions to write in that directory.

Comment: Yes, it's Linux based NAS appliance, but it's strange, since I've created the directory through the same share with the same mount config (not locally on that device).